# Azure AD Application Roles for Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, active-directory, asp.net-web-api2

I have secured a web api 2 project using Azure AD. This works perfectly well using the [Authorize] attribute, but I cannot get it to work with roles. I have added the following to the application manifest:

```
"appRoles": [
{
  "allowedMemberTypes": [
    "Application"
  ],
  "description": "Access to example controller",
  "displayName": "Example",
  "id": "76d4bbb5-24c1-45ad-9446-cc360d7bd012",
  "isEnabled": "true",
  "origin": "Application",
  "value": "example"
}
```

]

and this attribute to my api controller: [Authorize(Roles="example")]. If I remove this attribute and call my api this claim is included for ClaimsPrincipal.Current:

```
{http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role: example}
```

but this isn't enough to allow my application to authenticate when the roles header is used. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the token is a SAML token, rather than JWT. So to get this working I just needed to set this in my TokenValidationParameters

```
TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    // we inject our own multitenant validation logic
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    // map the claimsPrincipal's roles to the roles claim
                    RoleClaimType = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role",

                }
```

Comment: Is this web api enabled for multi-tenancy ?

Comment: How do you assign roles to Web api enabled for multi-tenant access. From a different Azure AD directory you cannot see Web api to be able to assign roles on it

Comment: I'm not sure actually, that's not something I've done. I'm sure if you create a new question someone will be able to answer that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your ConfigureAuth function should be like this

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
    new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Audience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"],
        Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],
        TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
        {
            RoleClaimType = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role"
        }
    });        
}
```

And then you can add Authorize attribute to your api as

```
 [Authorize(Roles = "example")]
```